# How do I tell py2app to use/include 32bit Python (for wxPython)?

Tags: python, wxpython, osx-lion, 32bit-64bit, py2app

I'm using OS X Lion (10.7.3) and I'm trying to write a cross-platform, stand-alone GUI-based program using `wxPython` and `py2app`.

I tried to use Python 2.7.1 which comes shipped with Lion.

I got the `wxPython2.8` binaries (wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7).

I installed `py2app` via pip.

This is my little test app:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'test.py')
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

This is my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    app=["test.py"],
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

wxPython 2.8 wants 32-bit mode, so I use the `arch` command:

```
arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.7 test.py
```

**How do I tell py2app to use/include 32bit Python?**

It is possible to manually exchange the relevant files in the app bundle, but that's a rather clumsy workaround. I could also use 64bit wxPython2.9, but there isn't a stable release available yet. Should I switch to `cx_Freeze`? What is the best practice here?

Comment: so is your `/usr/bin/python2.7` installation 32 or 64 bit? if it's 64, you've got to install the 32 bit version and use that.

Comment: file /usr/bin/python2.7 (Python 2.7.1) tells me it's a universal binary with 2 architectures (64 bit and 32 bit).
The 32 bit-only Python 2.7.3 from python.org isn't made for OSX 10.7.

Comment: I installed python-2.7.3-macosx10.3.dmg which doesn't support 64 bit and it actually helped. However, now I have a default python which unnecessarily supports PPC architecture and the whole package was actually made for 10.3 instead for 10.7. Is this really the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 64 bit Python installed, then it will create a 64 bit application.
If you have 32 bit Python installed, then it will create a 32 bit application.

If you have both installed, then what is created will depend on where Python collects it's libraries from, the 32 bit or 64 bit install folders.
  On Windows, this depends on which Python executable is actually run. And this depends on which is first in your system or user PATH settings.

When you type **python setup.py**, Windows runs **python.exe** which python.exe is run from the command line depends on you **PATH** environemnt variable.  Which is run if you douple click **setup.py** in explorer depends on you file associations with **.py** files.

You could easily make setup.py ensure the correct is being run by spawning a 32bit python instance from within an arbitrary one.

Comment: P.S. If you are on Linux then, generally the same PATH rule applies. However because of symlinks some systems might do something more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think it's just a PATH issue. On OSX python is represented as a single file supporting multiple architectures. I think it consists of several combined Mach-O files.